# How to authorize API endpoint using API Key and Private Key in PEM format?

Tags: android, api, security, authorization, pem

Thanks for looking into my question.

My Android application wants to talk to an API endpoint which requires all API requests to be signed using API Key and Private key in PEM format. When I open the .pem file using notepad, the contents appears to be wrapped in "---- BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY--- " and "------ END RSA PRIVATE KEY --- " tags.

I'm using Retrofit library client for network calls. I've configured an OkHttpClient interceptor to intercept and adds an "Authorization" header to the outgoing request.

OkHttpClient code looks like this:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
    okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();
            Log.d(TAG, "Request body: "  + originalRequest.body());

            Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder().header("Authorization",
                    signAndGetHeaderString(context));

            Request newRequest = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    });
```

signAndGetHeaderString() looks like this:

```
private String signAndGetHeaderString(Context context) {
    try {

        Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        s.initSign(getPrivateKey(context));
        s.update(new Date().toString().getBytes());
        byte[] signature = s.sign();
        String headerStr = "Signature keyId=\"" + API_KEY + "\",algorithm=\"rsa-sha256\",signature=\"" + new String(ByteString.encodeUtf8(new String(signature)).base64()) + "\"";
        return headerStr;
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The code compiles and executes but still fails with a 401 Unauthorized error.

I have verified and confirmed that the credentials works fine. 
Any idea why it fails? Thanks for the help.